# VBA click on webpage open pop-up but then do nothing

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a code in VBA-Excel in which I navigate into a webpage, login in it and after that, move to another url within the site. Up to there everything is apparently working well, but after all that done, I do need to click on a link in the site (that is in a frame section). I have the following piece of code that do the click, and I think it works because a pop-up/modal window opens with the next page, which is a form I need to complete.

```
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLdoc_F.getElementsByTagName("a")
Debug.Print oHTML_Element.innerText
If oHTML_Element.innerText = "Persona Natural " Then
    oHTML_Element.Click
    Loop Until HTMLdoc_F.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Exit For
End If 
Next
```

The thing is that when executing the oTHML_Element.click line, it opens the link but stays in the same line forever. I have tried FireEvent onclick an other method and the result is the same.

The html part is this:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">


<script language="javascript">


function ShowfrmIndividual(){
    window.showModalDialog("Response.ASP?WCI=TIndividual&WCU=&RoleTypeId=1&CustomerTypeId=1&Cached=0","Dialog Arguments Value","dialogHeight: 570px; dialogWidth: 800px; dialogTop: px; dialogLeft: px; edge: Raised; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: Yes; status: No;");
    return false;
}

</script></head>


<body bgcolor="#efebef" link="#ffffff" vlink="#efebef" alink="#efebef" ms_positioning="GridLayout">
<table border="0" width="1359" bgcolor="#ff7908" height="20" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: 6">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td width="100%"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>

<a style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 210px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 56px;  TEXT-INDENT: 0px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: MS Serif; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 121px; HEIGHT: 16px; TEXT-ALIGN: left" onclick="return ShowfrmIndividual()" href="https://www.anysite.cl/Chile/RWeb/Response.ASP?WCI=TMainWelcome&amp;amp;WCU=&amp;amp;amp;WCE=eActivities&amp;amp;amp;WCU">...para una</a>
<a style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 210px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 110px; TEXT-INDENT: 0px; MARGIN-RIGHT: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: MS Serif; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 135px; HEIGHT: 16px; TEXT-ALIGN: left" onclick="return ShowfrmIndividual()" href="https://www.anysite.cl/Chile/RWeb/Response.ASP?WCI=TMainWelcome&amp;amp;WCU=&amp;amp;amp;WCE=eActivities&amp;amp;amp;WCU"> Persona Natural </a>

</form></body></html>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: If you use the following ie.navigate2 "https://www.filink.cl/Chile/RWeb/Response.ASP?WCI=TMainWelcome&WCU=&WCE=eActivities&WCU"  instead of click lines and loop do you end up at the same place?

Comment: @QHarr the URI called in the `window.showModalDialog()` javascript function is different than the `href` of that element, so I don't think he ends up on the same place. Felipe, just for info, the `window.showModalDialog()` is deprecated since years (but I guess you don't control the website, you just want to scrape it). If my memory works, it opens a pop-up in dialog mode so the browser doesn't get the thread back until the form is closed. I guess that's why the code stops in that line (at least until you don't close the form manually).

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Thanks. So it is getting a handle on that window then?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I think the same you mentioned. Do you know any workaround? Indeed I do not control the website.

Comment: Can you tell us if when you close the form you get the handle back?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ It opens the window so I suppose it does, but it never moves to next line in the VBA unless I close the new window. That's where I get idea-less.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ yep. as soon as I close the window the vba goes to next line and continue

Comment: I can't know it for sure if I don't test it myself, but I fear that `window.showModalDialog()` passes the handle to the browser and so, there is nothing you can do with VBA anymore: neither you can fill the form, nor you can close it. VBA will keep on waiting for the browser to give it the handle back. Since you can't change the website to use this deprecated method, the only thing I can suggest you is you automate this using a language that allows multi-threading (java, python, c++ etc.). Unfortunately VBA has only one thread, and if the browser doesn't give it back, it's dead.